# Extract data from GeoJSON based on user input and write to pandas data.frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, geojson

I have a large GeoJSON file (100k+ nested dictionaries). This is the layout of the GeoJSON:

```
[
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 2625,
        "id": "ZWL_4983539",
        "label": "PZ005",
        "timestamp_from": "2018-06-16T13:00:00.000Z",
        "timestamp_to": "2018-06-16T14:00:00.000Z",
        "value_NO2": 14.48,
        "unit_NO2": "ug/m3",
        "value_PM10": 29.07,
        "unit_PM10": "ug/m3",
        "value_RH": 39.64,
        "unit_RH": "%",
        "value_P": 1014,
        "unit_P": "hPa"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            6.0624,
            52.54120000000001,
            0
        ]
    }
},
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "OBJECTID": 2626,
        "id": "ZWL_4983451",
        "label": "PZ006",
        "timestamp_from": "2018-06-16T14:00:00.000Z",
        "timestamp_to": "2018-06-16T15:00:00.000Z",
        "value_NO2": 23.1,
        "unit_NO2": "ug/m3",
        "value_PM10": 21.27,
        "unit_PM10": "ug/m3",
        "value_RH": 35.21,
        "unit_RH": "%",
        "value_P": 1014,
        "unit_P": "hPa"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            6.055100000000001,
            52.53820000000002,
            0
        ]
    }
}]
```

The full GeoJSON can be accessed through:

```
response = requests.get('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/97d710812a4a49369bd064b5be69fcd4_0.geojson')
js = json.loads(response.text)
```

I want to define a function that extracts a subset of data from the GeoJSON and writes it to a dataframe. The function input should be a sensor label, time-period (from-to), and desired value (PM10, NO2 etc.):

```
def jsonToDataFrame(label, timestamp_from, timestamp_to, unit):
```

the function should work such that the following input:

```
jsonToDataFrame(PZ001, 2018-06-16T14:00:00.000Z, 2018-06-16T19:00:00.000Z, Value_PM10)
```

returns the following dataframe:

[image]

I have been struggling for a while to acquire the desired dataframe. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GeoDataFrame` from `Geopandas` instead of a Pandas dataframe. You can immediately load the geojson into a GeoDataFrame, which has the same structure and functionality as a Pandas dataframe.

```
import geopandas as gpd

path_to_geojson = "path/to/geojson"

df = gpd.read_file(path_to_geojson)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That would indeed be a much easier solution. However, due to the size of the geojson i try to avoid loading it directly to a geodataframe. It takes a while to process

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ijson](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson) to load only what you need from the JSON data in an iterative fashion, with low memory consumption, and filter the content you actually need. Then you can convert your results into a data frame.